# Ruby on Rails - Excluding a single domain from some routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, constraints

In Rails route, usually we do constraints: {domain: "example.com" } if we want to specify specific routes that example.com can have. But how do I reverse this such that everyone can access this except example.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create custom constraint. Add more excluded domains if you want.

```
class DomainConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    excluded_hosts = ['example.com']
    excluded_hosts.exclude?(request.host)
  end
end
```

Use it like this:

```
constraints DomainConstraint.new do
  ..
end
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints